# Gaussian Filtering a Matrix Along 2 Axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, gaussian

I am trying to filter a matrix with a Gaussian  but using a different sigma for the x- and y-axes. The x-axis represents horizontal coordinates and the y-axis time and therefore I want to filter them differently.

Filtering with one sigma i can do but I don't know how to filter with two sigmas specific to the axis. I use imgaussfilt.

```
% example values
A = rand(6000,1921);
sigma_x = 10;
sigma_y = 20;
B = imgaussfilt(A,sigma_x);
B = double(B)/ max(B(:));
imshow(B)
colormap(jet)
colorbar
```

I would be glad for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html#bunfgk6-1-sigma), the `sigma` parameter to `imgaussfilt` can be a 2-element vector:

```
A = rand(6000,1921);
sigma_x = 10;
sigma_y = 20;
B = imgaussfilt(A,[sigma_y,sigma_x]);
B = double(B)/ max(B(:));
imshow(B)
colormap(jet)
colorbar
```

Note the order here: The first element indicates the *height* of the filter, the second one the *width*.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the functions involved, I suspected this would be the answer. +1